# what is the correct way to return a value inside of a method? in python

Tags: python, object

This function makes a range of dates (this function is related to a class):

```
def _makeRangeDates(self, desde, ultima_carga):
    dates = []
    for fechaRequest in rrule(DAILY, dtstart=desde, until=ultima_carga):
        dates.append(fechaRequest)
    return self.dates
```

What is the best way to return the list of dates inside of this function?

is mandatory to return self.dates ?

Regards.
Nelson.

Comment: well first off, `dates` and `self.dates` are two different objects.  You'll get different results.

Comment: `_makeRangeDates` isn't a method, just a function, since it doesn't read or write the object (it never uses its `self` parameter).  So either make it a function (outside the class), or a classmethod/staticmethod.

Comment: sorry my english and thanks for all your responds,
now is very clear for me, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you've got this function in some sort of class `foo` like so:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dates = []

    def _makeRangeDates(self,desde,ultima_carga):
        dates = []
        for fechaRequest in rrule(DAILY, dtstart=desde, until=ultima_carga):
            dates.append(fechaRequest)
        return self.dates
```

In this case returning `dates` and `self.dates` are two totally different things.  Since `dates` is created within the `_makeRangeDates` function, it will be garbage collected soon after the function is called.  If you're looking to just return `dates` and not save it in some state then that's perfect fine.

If you're hoping to save the state of `dates` then do the following:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dates = []

    def _makeRangeDates(self,desde,ultima_carga):

        for fechaRequest in rrule(DAILY, dtstart=desde, until=ultima_carga):
            self.dates.append(fechaRequest)
        return self.dates
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't return `self.dates` here. You are appending your dates in `dates` variable and that should be returned inside the method. In your case, `self.dates` might not even exist.

Edit: I think this is what you are trying to implement

```
class abc():
    def __init__(self):
        self.dates = []

    def _makeRangeDates(self,desde,ultima_carga):
        for fechaRequest in rrule(DAILY, dtstart=desde, until=ultima_carga):
            self.dates.append(fechaRequest)
        return self.dates
```

Comment: Without know the scope of the rest of his code, he actually *could* return `self.dates`.  It just wouldn't be wise as it's probably not the result he's looking for.

Comment: I know that! This was the best I could tell with the information provided

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing local variables and data members. And **`_makeRangeDates` isn't even a method, just a function**, since it doesn't read or write the object (you never use the `self` parameter).

`dates` is just some local variable you created inside your function with:

```
dates = []
    for fechaRequest in rrule(DAILY, dtstart=desde, until=ultima_carga):
        dates.append(fechaRequest)
```

`dates` is not a data member, i.e. it's not `self.dates`.

If you just want a function which returns that result, then `return dates`.
That function can stand outside the class hierarchy.

If you want to put a helper function like this inside a class, but which doesn't actually access the object at all, that sort of function is called a  **staticmethod / classmethod** (suggest you read up about the difference between the two).

Answer (score 0):

The `dates` variable and `self.dates` variable are two different variables (unless you do some assignment such as `self.date = date` , after this assignment they both are referring to the same object (but are still different names/variables pointing to same reference) .

And yes you can return any of them python should not complain (unless you are trying to return a variable that has not been defined/initialized , like you are doing in your example)

In your example you are creating `dates` variable and appending values to it, but at the end you are returning `self.dates` (which may cause issues since `self.dates` may not have been defined when the function is called).

I believe you want to return `dates` from your function , since that is the variable which you define in the function and to which you append the dates .